# How to find Average from Object.value - error NaN

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the average from Object.age. After the second age input I'm getting this:

50

25

NaN

How can I fix my function and is there another better way to do it?
I appreciate any help.

```js
// Statistic - Age Average
function statisticAgeAvg(){
    let avgArray = [];
    let avg = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        avgArray.push(parseInt(data[i].age));
        avg = avgArray / avgArray.length;
    }
    
    console.log(avg);
    candAvg.innerText = avg;
}
```

Comment: your calculation is wrong, it should be total of age / avgArray.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Average is the sum divided by the length, not the array divided by the length. Keep a running sum:

```js
let avgArray = [];
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
    let parsed = parseInt(data[i].age);
    sum += parsed;
    avgArray.push(parsed);
}
let avg = sum / avgArray.length;
```

Note that, if you're **only** looking for the average, you don't even need to maintain an array. You can just maintain a sum and a length.

Comment: you should take the avg calculation outside the loop, it makes no sense inside it, you are calculating average every time the data array is looped.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.

```
let data = [
  { age: 16 },
  { age: 9 },
  { age: 42 },
  { age: 1 }
];
// Statistic - Age Average
function statisticAgeAvg(_data){
  return _data.reduce((a,c) => a + c.age, 0) / _data.length
}

console.log(statisticAgeAvg(data)); // 17
```

Answer (score -1):

couple of ways do it, Should be total divided by array length

```
var total = 0;
var data=[1,10,25,50];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    total += data[i];
}
var avg = total / data.length;
console.log(avg)

let average = (array) => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length;
console.log(average(data));
```